# TechNet, licensing and virtual machines (VM)

Tags: virtual-machines, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a TechNet Subscription and have (1) Windows Server 2008 product key. It says this type is MultipleActivation.  My question is... if I installed the key on a VM, and then later wanted to delete the VM, can I reuse the same product key?  Will I be penalized for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, is yes.

You can install a server with that key, activate it and delete the VM over and over if you wish.

For example, if you were allowed 1 activation of a product key before it expired, and formatted/deleted the machine, you would be able to use and activate again, as its still in the boundaries of the agreement.

Comment: Great help, thanks!!! Would you happen to have a link to where it specifies this by the way?